# Prove the Triangularisability of T

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $k$-vectorial space and $T$ be an element of $\operatorname{Hom}(V, V)$.Suppose you have $k = \mathbb{C} $ and $\operatorname{Dim} V=2$, show that every $T$ belonging to $\operatorname{Hom}(V, V)$ is triangularizable (There is a basis of V with respect to which $T$ has an upper triangular matrix).

---

I've seen a demonstration in the book  "Linear Algebra Done Right" which proves it for all finite dimensions, but there are some concepts that I can't fully understand. I read that in the complex field ($\mathbb{C}$), the matrix is ​​triangularizable when all its eigenvalues ​​belong to $\mathbb{C}$ (but I guess to use this I should prove it). Then, I thought that if I used the characteristic polynomial to calculate its roots, all the values ​​were going to be complex numbers, then their eigenvalues ​​would belong to the complexes. But i don't feel it's the right way.

---

In a book, I saw that if $\operatorname{Dim} V=1$, then the result was fulfilled in a "direct" way (Is this because if $\operatorname{Dim}V=1$, all matrices can be considered as a upper-triangular matrix? Or am I misinterpreting the concept of dimension on this occasion?). I'd appreciate some help to find how to prove it for $\operatorname{Dim}V=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is upper triangular. This means that
$$
T(v_1)=av_1,\quad T(v_2)=bv_1+cv_2
$$
for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$. In particular, you see that $a$ should be an eigenvalue for $T$ and $v_1$ an eigenvector relative to it (so you see why $\mathbb{C}$ is needed, because there are real matrices that don't have real eigenvalues).

Take $v_2$ any vector so that $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis. Then, by assumption, $T(v_1)=av_1$ and $T(v_2)=bv_1+cv_2$ for some $b,c\in\mathbb{C}$. Done.